# C# .NET: Problems with query strings with character references

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode, special-characters, query-string

I'm having problems creating a query string and sending it to another webpage.

The text I'm trying to send is long and has special characters. Here is an example:

Represent a fraction 1/𝘣 on a number line diagram by defining the interval from 0 to 1 as the whole and partitioning it into 𝘣 equal parts. Recognize that each part has size 1/𝘣 and that the endpoint of the part based at 0 locates the number 1/𝘣 on the number line.

I can send this just fine if I hand code it:

```
     <a href="Default.cshtml?standardText=Represent a fraction 1/&#120355; on a number line diagram by defining the interval from 0 to 1 as the whole and partitioning it into &#120355; equal parts. Recognize that each part has size 1/&#120355; and that the endpoint of the part based at 0 locates the number 1/&#120355; on the number line.">
        Link Text
    </a>
```

This goes through without any problems, and I can read the entire Query String on the other side.

But if I am creating the link programmatically, my query string gets cut off right before the first character reference. I am using the following setup in a helper function:

```
string url = "Default.cshtml";
url += "?standardText=" + standard.text;
<a href="@url">Link Text</a>
```

When I use this, I only get "Understand a Fraction as 1/" and then it stops.

When I look at the page source, the only difference in the links is that one has actual ampersands and the second is having those turned into &

```
<a href="Default.cshtml?standardText=Understand a fraction 1/&amp;#120355; as the quantity formed by 1 part when a whole is partitioned into &amp;#120355; equal parts; understand a fraction &amp;#120354;/&amp;#119887; as the quantity formed by &amp;#120354; parts of size 1/&amp;#120355;."
```

So the problem is not really the spaces, but the fact that the & is being interpreted as starting a new query string parameter.

I have tried various things [using HttpUtility.UrlEncode, HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode, Html.Raw, trying to replace spaces with "+"], but the problem isn't with the spaces, its with how the character references are being handled.  When I tried HttpUtility.urlEncode I got a double-encoding security error.

On the advice of OmG I tried replacing all the &s, #s, and /s using:

```
url = url.Replace("&","%26");
url = url.Replace("#","%23");
url = url.Replace("/","%2F");
```

This led to the following link:

```
    <a href="Default.cshtml?standardText=Understand a fraction 1%2F%26%23120355; as the quantity formed by 1 part when a whole is partitioned into %26%23120355; equal parts; understand a fraction %26%23120354;%2F%26%23119887; as the quantity formed by %26%23120354; parts of size 1%2F%26%23120355;.">All Items</a>
```

And now when I click on the link I get a different security warning/error:

*A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (standardText="...raction 1/𝘣 as the qua...").*

I don't see why it is so hard to send character references through a QueryString. Is there a way to prevent Razor from converting all my &s to the &amp ; ? The address works fine when it is just plain "&"s.

Update: using URLDecode() on the string does not affect its character entity references, so when I try to decode the string then re-encode it, I still get the double-escape security warning.

Update: on the suggestion of @MikeMcCaughan, I tried using JS, but I am not very knowledgeable about mixing JS and Razor.  I tried creating a link by dropping a script into the body like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
        a.appendChild(linkText);
        a.title = "my title text";
        a.href = encodeURIComponent(@url);
        document.body.appendChild(a);

    </script>
```

But no link showed up, so I'm obviously doing it wrong.

For reference, when I try to use @Html.Raw(url),

```
<a href="@Html.Raw(url)">Link Text</a>
```

The &s are still turned into &amp ;s. the link renders as:

```
<a href="Player.cshtml?standardText=Represent a fraction 1/&amp;#120355; on a number line diagram by defining the interval from 0 to 1 as the whole and partitioning it into &amp;#120355; equal parts. Recognize that each part has size 1/&amp;#120355; and that the endpoint of the part based at 0 locates the number 1/&amp;#120355; on the number line.">Link text</a>
```

Comment: Are you doing this in Web Forms or MVC?

Comment: Never mind, I saw the mention of Razor. You can use `@Html.Raw(url)` to get it to not convert `&` to `&amp;`, IIRC.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, using @HTML.Raw() was one of the first things I did, and it works fine if I am just outputting the value of the string to the page, but when I try to use it inside the link with <a href="Html.Raw(url)">text</a>, the &s are still converted to &amp ;s.

Comment: From my experimentation, the URL that ends up there, while it has `&amp;` in the attribute, still passes `&` when you click on the URL. Is that not the case?

Comment: One question is, what is in `standard.text`? Does it have "" or "&#120355;" in it?

Comment: It has &#120355;

The link is to another cshtml page that has

string standardText = Request.QueryString["standardText"];

and when I use @Html.Raw(url) as the link and then try to display it on the next page using

@Html.Raw(standardText)

The string is cut off. So I'm assuming that the value of QueryString["standardText"] is being truncated due to the &

Comment: A friend who worked as a .NET developer for many years indicated that I need to use "\u" instead of "&#x" to escape unicode strings... but unfortunately, that only works for hexadecimal strings.

When I replace &#120355; with \U0001d623, it works great. [\U for 8-digit hex]

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is replacing the special characters by their encoding which can be accessed from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

As you can find, replace in the string `&` with `%26` using `.replace` for `string`. Also, replace `/` with `%2F`, `#` with `%23`, `;` with `%3B`, and space with `%20`.

Also, You can do these in C# by the following function:

```
Server.URLEncode("<The Url>")
```

and in Javascript by the following function:

```
encodeURI("<The Url>")
```

Also, as you know the double-encoding is [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Double_Encoding). To prevent the double-encoding, you should have not encoded some part of the string before passing the string into the `Server.URLEncode` function.

Comment: When using Server.URLEncode(), I get the same double-encoding character error as I get with HttpUtilityUrlEncode().

When I try to replace & with "%26", the receiving page no longer is able to parse the query string at all. Request.QueryString["standardText"] returns an empty string.

Comment: See my update on the post: "Also, as you know the double-encoding is this. To prevent the double-encoding, you should have not encoded some part of the string before passing the string into the Server.URLEncode function."

Comment: I did not do the encoding. The data is provided to me.

Any idea why encoding &'s prevents query string from being readable?

Comment: Okay, actually I made an error when replacing the &s, but it did not fix the problem. I then tried replacing &s, #s, and \s, and I got an other security error: "A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client..."

Comment: @DavidR So, you should apply `Server.URLDecode` on the string, then apply the encoder.

Comment: I tried that. Server.URLDecode does not appear to change character entity references, so I still get the same double-encoding error. The output of Server.URLDecode(url) still has entity references in it like &#120355;

Comment: One should typically use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) rather than [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI), since the latter does not encode things like `&`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, thanks for the note... sadly I'm not very good at combining Javascript with Razor.  I edited the main post with what I tried without success.